# vega-lite: Error on drag-drop of interval selection

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a vega-lite chart having `interval` and `single` selections. I am getting an error in logs as `[Error] Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Refer the attached chart in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-G6gA8AF5-caOaasRrcdrZLqbQAyNN+tRGpVcnl8gURmNKk15hlM4aph0quCrNhQO7e31KhYQw7IWSMpWslEgADCanIbG0AE8QMKlI0RxDHiBkNpomFMCPwfocJcWd8gQMqZEGHAlBBRuU3J5hMS93BUhAWnAoH0EZpwrf70uV2MQGt0tpiLDEY+QBOBA2AYG9lDYWxZBOABCOBSGGSgIBgGhvEwABpOARyFGC4IFSh710DCsIUG17FkcDbFQYDQLgBgcFtPVSLWCiqJAm9gNIaDESKNh3TQbxYRvJREBwZd9DdWRSlSW4HFmJ9l1XdAvwhX89CUJhmP0aBYTVf95HQIC2NrCCoNwhCkJQ9DMKFEiyJY6ibzohimPIiDWJoji4C43oPn2aUP0MmiKNM+DMEQ5DUKImyXPsoynJtRi7LchzEDYTjuN4450FseAWmgk4zLCizIusxERLE9AJKkpQZOUAANN9FM-YYVL-dTNPQbTgT0-RArAkyCtC-DIkEKLbOY5K4vohKYsmjy0q8xFdj8wdepS4LBrwgjRus8bXMolL4sSiaDqMzzvJAHi+Oy3LBHywrhsI0rhIQUSx0quRqowPwYGEMgsEaj8j3WAZESgAZTH4wSDxAZkvFWdYUROEAvHhbQQBFVI4bYBGNlADIcmCSl9DLXkK2yXp330ABHBg9j6dQ+lIVkpjCWq0EvXp+g-UmC03EB2zUfQFHRrmoGiPsQJZTZr3FMZQBKKIocEG9tiUd7QApKkQFVYNLWTJaqfQWn6boNQaGZpQajqJduYBIMCFDBFvmHZBsnQEWls9aIUQElWYb6cXJYYaWtkPOWwkVthldV1JfDhAB5HBeToDWUbkVYH300B0giMI9ipM5nwGe92H077-r+gHUgGdZ6AACjlJB64AHQr36fswEEImHOA24ASn7jHUlU-c0FcSgAE4R9hMfkkoKpPDYNHbcwUHUFkKVBC3X59AHdIyGHMdKaat0PVkNqQAGMhmSpJ5tGCaWQAf-6Kav+Y2g6Y9xgAJjVtJeKCD6MSIuWt9AADkkD8i9mvD8kDoEnw-GfK4ehRQCyJtrXWFokz4hgevHWDsnbyEQTTOmwwzZMy+ALV2QsPaUB-t4cchJ0G7xpHScs-J+YM3wbzcmhsmom3IYzC2VDBbu0UPQxhwptgiiAA) or the code below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/cars.json"
  },
  "width": 500,
  "config": {
    "view": {"strokeWidth": 0},
    "text": {"fontSize": 13},
    "axis": {"labelFontSize": 13, "titleFontSize": 13},
    "axisY": {"labelPadding": 5}
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "average",
          "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
          "as": "avg_Miles_per_Gallon"
        },
        {"op": "average", "field": "Displacement", "as": "avg_Displacement"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['Miles_per_Gallon']>datum['avg_Miles_per_Gallon'] ? 'Economic' : datum['Miles_per_Gallon']<=datum['avg_Miles_per_Gallon'] && datum['Displacement']<datum['avg_Displacement'] ? 'Mediocre' : 'Performance'",
      "as": "Category"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true, "size": 150, "clip": true},
      "selection": {
        "select": {
          "type": "interval",
          "on": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey][!event.ctrlKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": false,
          "empty": "none"
        },
        "gridY": {
          "type": "interval",
          "bind": "scales",
          "on": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "translate": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": "wheel![event.shiftKey]",
          "empty": "none"
        },
        "gridX": {
          "type": "interval",
          "bind": "scales",
          "on": "[mousedown[event.ctrlKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "translate": "[mousedown[event.ctrlKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": "wheel![event.ctrlKey]",
          "empty": "none"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "type": "single",
          "clear":false,
          "encodings": ["color"]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Displacement",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": true,
            "title": "Displacement",
            "format": ",r",
            "tickCount": 5
          },
          "scale": {"zero": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Miles/Gallon",
            "format": ",r",
            "ticks": false,
            "tickCount": 5
          },
          "scale": {"zero": false}
        },
        "fillOpacity": {
          "condition": {
            "test": {
              "and": [
                {"selection": "highlight"},
                "length(data(\"highlight_store\"))"
              ]
            },
            "value": 0.9
          },
          "value": 0.3
        },
        "color": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "Category",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"orient": "right", "labelFontSize": 12}
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Name", "title": "Name", "type": "nominal"},
          {
            "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
            "title": "Miles/Gallon",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "format": ",.2f"
          },
          {
            "field": "Displacement",
            "title": "Displacement",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "format": ",.2f"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The steps are:

1. Apply an interval selection on some points.
2. Drag and move the applied interval rectangle on other points.
3. I get an error in logs as mentioned above.

What can be the reason for this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: Can anyone confirm, if this issue is related to this one https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7436

Comment: Raised a ticket for the above question https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7476.